# How to properly add and access a JavaScript file in Wordpress?

Tags: theme-development, javascript, page-template

I intend to use a JavaScript library on my WP website and have uploaded the JS file via FTP to the following directory belonging to the currently activated theme Salient: `/public_html/wp-content/themes/salient/js`

Then, in order to load the JavaScript, I have added the following line in the "Header and Footer" settings (to be injected before the body closing tag):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.mypage.../public_html/wp-content/themes/salient/js/javascriptfile.js"></script>
```

When I am then loading a page and when inspecting it using the Chrome console, there's a 404 error for that JS file, although the file and the directory exist. As an alternative approach I also tried to add the script reference directly in HTML and even the page template, but with the same result.

Why do I keep getting the 404 error? Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/

Comment: Thanks, but how does this address my question: what is wrong with the approach as I describe it, i.e. by using the Header & Footer plugin? https://www.collectiveray.com/wp/tips/add-javascript-to-wordpress

Comment: @F.Marks, you are providing invalid url for `src` attribute and result is 404 error. It should be something like `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.mypage.com/wp-content/themes/salient/js/javascriptfile.js"></script>` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enqueue your script using

```
wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer);
```

Where,
`$handle` is the name for the script.

`$src` defines where the script is located.

`$deps` is an array that can handle any script that your new script depends on, such as `jQuery`.

`$ver` lets you list a version number.

`$in_footer` is a `boolean` parameter (`true`/`false`) that allows you to place your scripts in the footer of your HTML document rather then in the header, so that it does not delay the loading of the DOM tree.

[**Documentation**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

**Add this code to `functions.php` file of your theme.**

```
function add_my_script() {

  wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', 
         get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/javascriptfile.js', 
         array ( 'jquery' ), 
         false,
         true
  );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
```

Comment: Thank you Qaisar. I added the code to functions.php. There's no 404 error in the console, but when looking at the source code I cannot find the JS file added/referenced.

Comment: Look for it somewhere just before closing `</body>` tag. If it is a on a live/online site please share link so I may help find it.

Comment: I found it, it was n't in because of a different error in functions.php which I have now also fixed, thanks Quaisar, I appreciate your kind help! I was very specific with my question and I am not a professional programmer, it is sad to see that someone downvoted my question (I do not assume it was you). Thanks so much again!! Frank

Comment: Stay blessed always! I don't know why someone down-voted your question, but I up-voted it just now.